# No LOAD DATA support in stored procedures in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, shell, stored-procedures, mysql-python

Actually I am trying to use LOAD DATA statement in MySQL stored procedure but I am getting this error :-

```
MySQL Database Error: LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures.
```

My Syntax is:-

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test.pro_load_data()
BEGIN
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'D:/K-WD/Experiments/Procedures/test_hospital_master.csv' 
     INTO TABLE test_hospital_master
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n';
END //
```

Is there any way to use LOAD DATA in STORED PROCEDURE using SHELL script?

Comment: Do you really need to use it in a stored procedure, especially when it's the only statement in an SP?

Comment: Yes I need this, actually i require some more statements but if its work then i can add later.

Comment: Just FYI, I find a possibly solution for the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053263/mysql-load-data-infile-when-conditions-are-met