# MySQL Load Data Infile when conditions are met

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement, load-data-infile

I am currently building a MySQL database. The database is storing data which is being supplied by another organisation and the format of the files we recieve is, shall we say, somewhat inconsistent.

I have writted a function which assess the file based on some simple rules and returns a message saying 'file ok' or else one of a list of hard coded error messages. The way I would like to use this function would be to say something like:

```
if check_10m_file() = 'file ok' then 
  load data infile '\\\\server\\filepath\file.csv'
  fields terminated by ','
  ...(etc)
```

My problem is that the `if..then..else` control structure does not seem to be allowed outside of stored procedures and the `load data infile` command is not allowed inside stored procedures.

I have attempted to trick my way around this by building the `load data infile` statement as a prepared statement but then I get an error

"This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet"

So my question is, does anyone know of a way in which I can run a load data statement only when conditions are met?  I would ideally like to put this into a stored procedure but if I could just save the code as a script to run later, that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-udf.html), for example: [lib_mysqludf_sys](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys).

After installing the UDF, you can do something like:

Shell script (/server/loadpath/load.sh):

```sh
mysql -u [user] -p[pass] -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '$1' INTO TABLE $2;"
```

Stored Procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS load_data$$

CREATE PROCEDURE load_data(pfile VARCHAR(100), pdbtable VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    DECLARE exec_str VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE ret_val INT;
    IF (check_10m_file() = 'file ok') THEN
        SET exec_str := CONCAT('sh /server/loadpath/load.sh ', pfile, ' ', pdbtable);
        SET ret_val := sys_exec(exec_str);
        IF ret_val = 0 THEN
            SELECT 'OK' Result;
        ELSE
            SELECT 'ERROR' Result;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL load_data('/server/filepath/file.csv', 'mydb.mytable');
```

**IMPORTANT:** Validate the input data to prevent any code injection.